# When running Sonar, does Sonar Runner "phone home" or sacrifice functionality?

Tags: java, firewall, analysis, sonarqube

I need to run Sonar behind a firewall in a company that provides me with Sonar itself but does not allow downloads from the Internet (automated or not).  This makes use of Sonar on maven problematic, because maven needs to contact its online repository.  (There is an effort to create a corporate mirror of the repository, but that's not done yet).

Now I see that there's a new (to us) "Sonar Runner" that can launch an analysis.  In fact, it's the default.  I have looked at some documentation (eg, http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Sonar+Runner) but I just want to nail down a couple details:

(1) will this work behind a firewall without it having to call out on the network (as maven does)?

(2) I realize that this will require that the code is already built outside of the Sonar analysis -- which is fine -- but will we lose any other features besides building in the analysis?

I'm just looking for confirmation from someone who really knows, before wasting my company's time.

Thank you!

--David

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, Sonar Runner will work on your local network as it does not need to download things from the Internet - only from the Sonar Web server instance (which seems to be on your intranet).
2. If your code is compiled before launching the Sonar analysis with the Sonar Runner, you'll be able to get all the reports that need bytecode (provided that you give the correct configuration of the "sonar.binaries" and "sonar.libraries" properties). If your unit tests have been run and the reports are kept somewhere, you will also be able to get test results in Sonar using the "reuseReport" mode.

To sum up, you will be able to get all the features you have when using Maven. This will juste required some extra configuration.